# catkin build error for moveit workspace setup

Tags: moveit, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to setup workspace for moveit. I'm following the steps mentioned in below link.

Tutorial steps:-  http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#install-ros-and-catkin

I'm receiving the below error when i run the catkin build.

```
Error - 
error: ‘class moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface’ has no member named ‘getJointModelGroupNames’
   std::copy(move_group.getJointModelGroupNames().begin(), move_group.getJointModelGroupNames().end(),
```

I have followed every step from those tutorial and i have no idea how can i solve this error.
any kind of help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307792/catkin-build-error-for-moveit-workspace-setup/) by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-11-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robotics Intelligence](https://answers.ros.org/users/38445/robotics-intelligence/) on 2018-11-09**:
I got same errors too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

installing moveit from source and then building solves this problem.
After building (approx 27 packages) you can clone the tutorials in the src folder of your workspace and run catkin build again.

---

Originally posted by [mvish7](https://answers.ros.org/users/38417/mvish7/) with karma: 104 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced the same issue. Try checking out the kinetic-devel branch of git repo kinetic_tutorials and then build again and might want to do the same for the panda_moveit_config repo if you need it.

```
cd ~/ws_moveit/moveit_tutorials
git checkout kinetic-devel
cd ~/ws_moveit
catkin build
```

---

Originally posted by [denbys](https://answers.ros.org/users/38452/denbys/) with karma: 41 on 2018-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-09**:
This should be the accepted answer.

It's likely that @mvish7 built the Melodic version of MoveIt from sources on Kinetic. That is not needed, as long as the tutorials are checked out as the Kinetic version.

**Comment by [vasko](https://answers.ros.org/users/38447/vasko/) on 2018-11-12**:
Thank you, it helped !!

**Comment by [qq95538](https://answers.ros.org/users/39051/qq95538/) on 2018-12-17**:
I use Kinetic, and meet this error. To change git devel is the correct answer.